# Yii2 $defaultValue in anonymous functions

Tags: php, function, yii2

Not a big problem,but i wanna figure it out why.
I was reading at Yii2 By Example.
And i noticed that view file in the exmaple of a db Transaction.
it's about dropdownlist,here is the code:

```
<?= $form->field($reservation, "room_id")->
dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(Room::find()->all(), 'id', 
function($room, $defaultValue) {
return sprintf('Room n.%d at floor %d', $room->room_number, $room->floor);
})); ?>
```

I tried it with and without the $defaultValue.Both worked.
so what is the use of the "$defaultValue"?
or it just a non-sence.
I googled it and have no idea.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the  yii2 reference  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basearrayhelper.html#map()-detail

in the map() function of the ArrayHelper you can use for from, to and group param a clousure too ..

then in the clusere you can pass th the inner function a list o param that are "visible" inside the function  in you case you don't use 
$defaultValue  so you could avoid to pass this var

```
  ArrayHelper::map(Room::find()->all(), 'id', 
  function($room) {
  return sprintf('Room n.%d at floor %d', $room->room_number, $room->floor);
  })
```

You could use also $test var and use it eg:

```
  $test = 'Big ';
  ArrayHelper::map(Room::find()->all(), 'id', 
  function($room) use($test) {
  return sprintf( $test . 'Room n.%d at floor %d', $room->room_number, $room->floor);
  })
```